# How to get History from TFS

Tags: c#, sql, tfs

Good day!

I need to know how to get History changes.For example,i spend 1 hour from task=>

```
               New Value Old Value   
Completed Work    19           18 
Original Estimate 19           18
```

How to get it from C#. As i know- i should use TSQL query.

How to get New Value and Old Value?

Thank you!